# Backup Yesterday Files in Folder

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I develop following script to gzip yesterday files in a directory, any improvements suggestions

```
Yesterday=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%d-%b-%y`;
mkdir $Yesterday
mv /tmp/logs/servicemix.log.* /tmp/logs/$Yesterday
for File in /tmp/logs/$Yesterday/app.log.*;
do gzip $File;
done
```

Regards

Comment: How do you make sure /tmp/logs/servicemix.log.* won't contain todays files?

Comment: I will make it cron job at 00:05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use following lines of codes**

```
TIME=`date +"%b-%d-%y"` # This Command will add date in Backup File Name.
now=$(date +"%T")
FILENAME="filename-$TIME:$now.tar.gz"      # Here i define Backup file name format.
SRCDIR="/home"              # Location of Important Data Directory (Source of backup).
DESDIR="/home/user/backup"     # Destination of backup file. 
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR #creating backup as tar file
echo
echo "Backup finished"
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Replace

```
mkdir $Yesterday
```

by

```
mkdir -p /tmp/logs/${Yesterday}
```

2. gzip the files you have moved
   When you move servicemix* files, do not gzip app* files

Answer (score -1):

Were they changed or created yesterday? Use `find` with the correct modifier.

```
Yesterday=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%d-%b-%y`;
mkdir $Yesterday

# -1 is equal to last 24 hours
# ctime is for last inode modified time. If you need creation date you need a different modifier. See attached link.
find -ctime -1 -exec mv '{}' "$yesterday/" \;
```

But [this is i think pretty much the best option: Use 'find' to determine files modified yesterday](https://serverfault.com/questions/72169/use-find-to-determine-files-modified-yesterday).

Comment: `-ctime` is changed time. I think this is the best best option.

Comment: @jm666 That's what i wrote. Changed time... I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @jm666 That's why the first line in my answer is changed or created? If the creation time matters than `ctime` is wrong. You are right about that.